# Why does the event "MouseLeftButtonUp" not work or get triggered most of the time?

Tags: wpf, mouseleftbuttonup

For simplifying the problem, I created a simple code snippet with the same problem:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Canvas x:Name="drawingCanvas" 
            MouseLeftButtonDown="drawingCanvas_MouseLeftButtonDown" 
            Background="White" 
            MouseMove="drawingCanvas_MouseMove" 
            MouseLeftButtonUp="drawingCanvas_MouseLeftButtonUp" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

When I try to use the `MouseLeftButtonUp` event, it does not work most of the time. Also by using `PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp`. Can someone tell me why it is like this and offer any suggestions to solve this problem?

```
namespace WPFTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            drawMode = false;
            startPoint = new Point();
            endPoint = new Point();
        }

        private bool drawMode;
        private bool alreadyForm;
        private Point startPoint;
        private Point endPoint;
        
        private void drawingCanvas_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            drawMode = true;
            alreadyForm = false;
            startPoint = e.GetPosition(drawingCanvas);
        }

        private void drawingCanvas_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            drawMode = false;
            alreadyForm = false;
            Debug.WriteLine("the event was detected.");
        }

        private void drawingCanvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (drawMode)
            {
                if (alreadyForm) 
                     drawingCanvas.Children.RemoveAt(drawingCanvas.Children.Count-1);

                endPoint = e.GetPosition(drawingCanvas);

                Line newLine = new Line();
                newLine.X1 = startPoint.X;
                newLine.Y1 = startPoint.Y;
                newLine.X2 = endPoint.X;
                newLine.Y2 = endPoint.Y;

                newLine.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
                newLine.StrokeThickness = 4;

                drawingCanvas.Children.Add(newLine);

                alreadyForm = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to solve the problem with the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp` event but it was the same.

I tried to use `e.Handled = true;` but it's also the same

Comment: If there's anything in the canvas then that'll get any mouse up or down events if the cursor is over them.

Comment: Are you sure about preview events?